# Python : list of strings to list of unique characters

Tags: python

I have a list of strings

```
ll = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']
```

I want a list of unique characters across all strings in the given list.

For ll, output should be

```
['a','b','c','d','x','y','z','k']
```

is there a clean way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This did not require deletion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to produce a *set* of the letters:

```
{l for word in ll for l in word}
```

You can always convert that back to a list:

```
list({l for word in ll for l in word})
```

Demo:

```
>>> ll = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']
>>> {l for word in ll for l in word}
{'b', 'a', 'x', 'k', 'd', 'c', 'z', 'y'}
```

You can also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to provide a single iterator over all the characters:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable(ll))
```

If you must have a list that reflects the order of the first occurrence of the characters, you can use a [`collections.OrderedDict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a set, then extract the keys with `list()`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(ll)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(ll)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'k']
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb: this was a borderline one; there is a blurry line between 'fix my code' and 'interesting algorithm question'. I answered because I did not think the other answers were good. It needed a better approach.

Comment: You probably know this, but dicts are ordered in [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict)

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: that's an implementation detail that is not yet part of the language specification.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, but interesting nonetheless

Answer (score 5):

I do not know the simplest way to do this, but I know one way:

```
list = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']
new=set()
for word in list:
    for letter in word:
        new.add(letter)
print(new)
```

This is an easy way for a beginner because it doesn't need any modules which you probably don't know how to use yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an inefficient way that preserves the order. It's ok when the total number of chars is small, otherwise, you should use Martijn's `OrderedDict` approach.

```
ll = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']
s = ''.join(ll)
print(sorted(set(s), key=s.index))
```

**output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'k']
```

---

Here's an alternative way to preserve the order which is less compact, but more efficient than the previous approach.

```
ll = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']
d = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(reversed(''.join(ll)))}
print(sorted(d, reverse=True, key=d.get))
```

**output**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'k']
```

Using `s.index` as the key function is inefficient because it has to perform a linear scan on the `s` string for each character that it sorts, whereas my `d` dict can get the index of each character in [O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). I use the `reversed` iterator because we want earlier chars to overwrite later duplicates of the same char, and using `reversed` is a little more efficient than building a new string with `[::-1]`.

Creating the `d` dict is only slightly slower than creating `set(s)`, and it may be a little faster than using `OrderedDict`, it certainly uses less RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `set()`

```
s = set()
 for word in ll:
   for letter in word:
     s.add(letter)
```

Now `s` should have all the unique letters. You can convert `s` to a list using `list(s)`.

Comment: Or `set(''.join(ll))`

Comment: Yeah, that seems cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` for that:

```
import itertools
ll = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']
set(itertools.chain(*[list(x) for x in ll]))

{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` would be cleaner. There is no need to convert the strings to lists, either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function you can call and give it the list and it will return all unique letters and I added it to print at the end

```
lst = ['abc', 'abd', 'xyz', 'xzk']

def uniqueLetters(lst1):
    unique = set()
    for word in lst1:
        for letter in word:
                unique.add(letter)
    return unique

print(uniqueLetters(lst))
```

To get a variable with the unique variables call the function like so:

```
uniqueLetters123 = uniqueLetters(lst)
```

And you can replace lst with your list name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 l2 =list()
 for i in ll:
    for j in i:
        l2.append(j)

 [''.join(i) for i in set(l2)]
```

output:

```
'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another one...

```
>>> set().union(*ll)
{'d', 'a', 'y', 'k', 'c', 'x', 'b', 'z'}
```

Wrap `list(...)` around it if needed, though why would you.